# How can I resolve these redraw issues in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every few minutes Visual Studio will completely go crazy.

[image]

- The content of tabs is offset.
- Code is not drawn at all.
- Clicking on tabs does nothing.
- Toolbox windows are also not rendered correctly

Only resizing the window temporarily fixes the issue, but only for a few more minutes and then it corrupts again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When experiencing graphical issues inside of Visual Studio, it can often be attributed to the use of hardware accelerated graphics. Thus, try disabling it.

1. Go to **Tools** then **Options**:

   [image]
2. The setting you're looking for is located in the **Environment** section:

   [image]

Comment: Good one to know! I've disabled it on mine now, curious to see if it results in less crashes/hangs/frustration.

Comment: In my case, the issue persists even after disabling hardware acceleration. Disabling the rich client visual experience also doesn't fix it.

Comment: I can't believe 3 years later and this is still an issue.  On my dual monitor setup, I always had redraw issues when dragging it to my DisplayPort monitor.  This solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @OliverSalzburg's answer; if disabling the hardware rendering fixes this issue for you, perhaps it would be an idea to try updating your graphics drivers.

I had the same issue, and fixed it by updating my graphics drivers. I'm running an AMD Fire Pro. The drivers that Windows update automatically installed caused the issue (version 15.x), updating to the latest version (16.x) fixed it for me.